# How to show LWC multi-line toasts?

Tags: lwc-wire-adapter, toast, lightning-web-components, lwc-dev-server, lwc.dev

Does anyone know how to implement multi-line with LWC ShowToastEvent?

I can only see workarounds using Aura but not LWC.

Answer (score 3):

There is no workaround for LWC. Either implement your own custom toast framework, or use an Aura wrapper. Those are your only options.